# Jenkins Reactive Choice reference param

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

I am trying to create pipeline where I change the input text based on the option I choose.

For the above case I used Active choice parameter and Reactive choice reference parameter. Where I referenced the name correctly.
I am able to fetch the active choice parameter value but I am not able to fetch Referenced choice parameters value in the build.

How to get the Active choice reference parameters value in the build.

Hope someone will help me on it.

Answer (score 0):

For any kind of jenkins pipeline param, to get value in pipeline script, do 'params.paramName'